# Picture change before fade out - setTimeout doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a photo slider which is working but i have a problem with changing arrows. When you click the arrow picture should fade out , change, and new picture fade in but my code first change picture after do fade animation. HELP

```
var slidenumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
var timerforslide = 0;
var timerforfade = 0;

function hideSlide() {
    $("#slide").stop();
    $("#slide").fadeOut(500);
}

function changeSlide() {
    resetSlideTimers();
    slidenumber++;
    if (slidenumber > 5) slidenumber = 1;
    if (slidenumber<1) slidenumber = 5;
    timerforfade = setTimeout("hideSlide()", 4500);
    timerforslide = setTimeout("changeSlide()", 5000);
    $("#slide").fadeIn(500);
    var file = "<img src=\"img/slide" + slidenumber + ".png\" width =\"100%\" height=\"300px\" /> "
    document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = file;



}

function resetSlideTimers() {
    clearTimeout(timerforfade);
    clearTimeout(timerforslide);
}

function nextSlide() {
    $("#slide").stop();
    resetSlideTimers();
    hideSlide();
    setTimeout(1000, changeSlide());

}

function previousSlide() {
    $("#slide").stop();
    resetSlideTimers();
    slidenumber = slidenumber - 2;
    hideSlide();
    setTimeout(500, changeSlide());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `setTimeout` call, the first argument is either an anonymous function or a reference to another function.  The second argument is the time to take to call that function.

So, your two function calls that are set like this:

```
timerforfade = setTimeout("hideSlide()", 4500);
timerforslide = setTimeout("changeSlide()", 5000);
```

are invalid because you are passing in a `string` not a `function`.  And you do not want to use parenthesis because that will immediately invoke the function **without waiting for the actual time lapse to occur**.  Change these to:

```
timerforfade = setTimeout(hideSlide, 4500);
timerforslide = setTimeout(changeSlide, 5000);
```

Remember, these are always either an anonymous function or a reference to a function.  Never put parenthesis unless it should be immediately invoked on that line of execution.

And the `setTimeout` created within `nextSlide` and `previousSlide` are reversed and have parenthesis. Change them, respectively, to:

```
//Next slide function
setTimeout(changeSlide, 1000);
//Previous slide function
setTimeout(changeSlide, 500);
```

I can't verify beyond that if your logic is correct right now, but those are some immediate errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your setTimeout syntax is off in three places:

```
timerforfade = setTimeout("hideSlide()", 4500);
timerforslide = setTimeout("changeSlide()", 5000);
```

should be (removed parentheses and quotation marks):

```
timerforfade = setTimeout(hideSlide, 4500);
timerforslide = setTimeout(changeSlide, 5000);
```

and

```
setTimeout(1000, changeSlide());
```

should be (changed order and removed parentheses)

```
setTimeout(changeSlide, 500);
```

setTimeout takes two arguments, the first one being a function that should be called once the timeout expires and the second one being the timeout in milliseconds. The function will be invoked immediately if you include parentheses, which is why your slide change happened before the fadeout:

```js
function alertFirst() {
  console.log("I should be first");
}

function alertSecond() {
  console.log("I should be second");
}

setTimeout(alertFirst, 500);
setTimeout(alertSecond(), 5000);
//                     ^
//                     |
//       Note the parentheses
```

With these changes it works as you (probably) intended: https://codepen.io/fdebijl/pen/WBLVYm